Can coaxial cables be passed through waveguides without compromising below-cutoff effects?
I have a waveguide (a hollow copper tube) in the wall of my shielded chamber and now I want to know if I can feed coaxial cables with heavy shielding (like CAT 7) through the waveguide or if this compromises the enclosure's shielding effectiveness as the cables consist of conductors internally.
Are there other options in general beside fiber-optical cables?

Just feed the cable in a smaller diameter tube bonded to the surface of the waveguide. How large is that waveguide - diameter and length?

Is the waveguide being actively driven by something or, is it used to collect some signal. I'm talking about the thing you call a waveguide rather than the coax. How you answer may determine what position that coax can assume.

If I understand you right, your real question is not really related to waveguides but whether a cable passed through the wall of your chamber can carry any disturbances? If so, then yes they can. Typically the best thing to do is to connect the cable shield to the wall of the chamber.

Having the cable going through the waveguide will prevent the waveguide from working. Is that a problem for you? || Also, category 7 cable is not coax. It's heavily shielded, yes, but it's not at all coax.

Probably not: the coax shield, inside the tube, makes another coaxial cable itself, and thus supports the TEM00 mode with propagation down to DC.  The coupling might not be all that strong, say if the jacket is PVC (poor dielectric at microwave frequencies, strong absorption), and the impedance match might be random, but the coupling will definitely be nonzero.
It will be up to you, to calculate or measure the attenuation of this geometry, or to determine what attenuation or isolation is required for the application.  Or what leakage is tolerable on the other side of this tube.
To prevent this, a bulkhead connector is needed, so that the coax shield becomes bonded to the chamber.  If this isn't practical (e.g. isolation is required?), a common mode filter can be used.  Which in this case, is just a normal mode filter, involving the coax cable's shield.  Without breaking the cable open, its internal signal remains referenced to the inner shield.  Put another way, the signal wire is perfectly coupled (to the extent the coax isn't leaky) to the shield, so to the extent the shield runs through a CLC(LC..) filter, the signal remains perfectly coupled through the chain of L's in that filter.
Capacitors aren't particularly easy to connect to an unbroken coax shield, while preserving good performance at microwave frequencies.  Bonding is preferred.

If shield isolation from the chamber is required, OP could go with a Triax cable, with the outer shield bonded to the chamber and the inner shield passing through.
